# Finding averages from strings in a list in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of scores like so:

```
scores = ["Bob Foo - 10 / 20\n",
      "Jim Foo - 5 / 20\n",
      "Bob Foo - 7 / 20\n",
      "Jack T - 6 / 20\n",
      "Jack T - 4 / 20\n",
      "Bob Foo - 9 / 20\n"]
```

I need to try and find the average score of each person seperately rounded to the nearest integer. The list may vary its scale and names will change but it will always have the format of:
*first name* *last name* - *score* / 20.

I want an output of something like:

```
>>> Bob Foo - 9
Jim Foo - 5
Jack T - 5
```

I really don't know what to do here. I know about the sorted function and how you can specify a key but I don't know if that will help here.

The closest I've gotten is:

```
for score in scores:
    print(re.split(r'[-/]',score))
```

which isn't even close, because all it does is split up the list and give me this:

```
>>> 
['Bob Foo ', ' 10 ', ' 20\n']
['Jim Foo ', ' 5 ', ' 20\n']
['Bob Foo ', ' 7 ', ' 20\n']
['Jack T ', ' 6 ', ' 20\n']
['Jack T ', ' 4 ', ' 20\n']
['Bob Foo ', ' 9 ', ' 20\n']
>>>
```

How can I overcome this? Can I just create a function that finds the average score of each person in a list?

Edit:

I could simplify the list of scores to an easier format. For example:

```
scores = ["Bob Foo 10\n",
      "Jim Foo 5\n",
      "Bob Foo 7\n",
      "Jack T 6\n",
      "Jack T 4\n",
      "Bob Foo 9\n"]
```

Comment: Perhaps you should have considered a more sensible save format to begin with?

Comment: @jordan Yes, I could simplify it to something like: Bob Foo 10

Comment: no i didnt see multiple entries ... just the first one ... is it always out of 10? shouldnt the average be a percentage?

Comment: Yes, the score is always out of 10 and I could make it could be a percentage, that would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it useful to divide-and-conquer programming tasks. Divide the complex task into a series of trivially simple tasks. Either you know how to do each one individually, or you can receive more targeted help on the part you are struggling with.

As an example, here is how I would solve this problem:

```
import re
scores = ["Bob Foo - 10 / 10\n",
          "John Smith - 5 / 10\n",
          "Bob Foo - 7 / 10\n",
          "Jack T - 6 / 10\n",
          "Jack T - 4 / 10\n",
          "Bob Foo - 9 / 10\n"]

# First, split the names and scores up
scores = [re.match('(\S+ \S+) - (\d+)', score).groups() for score in scores]
#print (scores)

# Convert the number string into an integer
scores = [[score[0], int(score[1])] for score in scores]
#print (scores)

# Create a dictionary, keyed by the name
names = set(score[0] for score in scores)
scores = {
    name: [score[1] for score in scores if name == score[0]]
    for name in names
}
# print (scores)

# Compute the average for each name
scores = {
    name: sum(score)/len(score)
    for name, score in scores.items()
}
print (scores)
```

Comment: That's great, and it works, however how can I now round the averages? For example, Bob Foo's average is 8.6 and I want 9

Comment: You could use the [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

```
parts = [score.split("-",1) for score in scores]
```

will break up your data how you demonstrated before except it just seperates it into name,rest , now you just need to save it

```
data = {}
for name,score in parts:
   try:
       data[name].append(score)
   except KeyError:
       data[name] = [score,]

print data
```

now you have grouped your scores by name so the now alll you need to do is go through and convert the score to actual `int`'s(or probably better `float`'s)
 and average the score for each name

Comment: I tried this code, but I get an *AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'* for *data[name].append(score)*     I am using python 3.

Comment: Thank you, but I get an odd output (for me.) I am not very good with dictionaries so, could you give an example of how I would convert the score to actual int's and average the score for each name ?

Answer (score 0):

try this .it might help you

```
import math
scores = ["Bob Foo - 10 / 10\n",
      "John Smith - 5 / 10\n",
      "Bob Foo - 7 / 10\n",
      "Jack T - 6 / 10\n",
      "Jack T - 4 / 10\n",
      "Bob Foo - 9 / 10\n"]
d={}  
for i in xrange(len(scores)):
    str=scores[i].split("-");
    try:
        (d[str[0]])[0] +=int((str[1].split("/"))[0])
        (d[str[0]])[1] +=1
    except:
        d[str[0]]=[0,0]
        (d[str[0]])[0]=int((str[1].split("/"))[0])
        (d[str[0]])[1]=1
//store sum and count in a dictionary 

for x in d:
    print x,((d[x])[0]/((d[x])[1])*1.0)
```

and in the last statement apply appropriate function ceil or floor .or round

[click here to see the execution](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import+math%0Ascores+%3D+%5B%22Bob+Foo+-+10+/+10%5Cn%22,%0A++++++%22John+Smith+-+5+/+10%5Cn%22,%0A++++++%22Bob+Foo+-+7+/+10%5Cn%22,%0A++++++%22Jack+T+-+6+/+10%5Cn%22,%0A++++++%22Jack+T+-+4+/+10%5Cn%22,%0A++++++%22Bob+Foo+-+9+/+10%5Cn%22%5D%0Ad%3D%7B%7D++%0Afor+i+in+xrange(len(scores))%3A%0A++++str%3Dscores%5Bi%5D.split(%22-%22)%3B%0A++++try%3A%0A++++++++(d%5Bstr%5B0%5D%5D)%5B0%5D+%2B%3Dint((str%5B1%5D.split(%22/%22))%5B0%5D)%0A++++++++(d%5Bstr%5B0%5D%5D)%5B1%5D+%2B%3D1%0A++++except%3A%0A++++++++d%5Bstr%5B0%5D%5D%3D%5B0,0%5D%0A++++++++(d%5Bstr%5B0%5D%5D)%5B0%5D%3Dint((str%5B1%5D.split(%22/%22))%5B0%5D)%0A++++++++(d%5Bstr%5B0%5D%5D)%5B1%5D%3D1%0A%0A%0Afor+x+in+d%3A%0A++++print+x,((d%5Bx%5D)%5B0%5D/((d%5Bx%5D)%5B1%5D)*1.0)%0A++++++++%0A&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=58)